# differential equation with substituion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, substitution

Solve for y:

$y'\tan(x+y)=1-\tan(x+y)$

so far I have made the substituion $u=x+y$, which yields $\frac{du}{dx}=1+\frac{dy}{dx}$. However, I am not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now substitute into the original equation: $y = u - x$, $y' = u' - 1$.  You should end up with a separable differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

\begin{align*}
\frac{dy}{dx}\tan(x+y) &= 1 - \tan(x+y) \ \ \ || \dot\ dx \ \ \ (1)
\\\tan(x+y)dy &= 1-tan(x+y)dx 
\\\int\tan(x+y)dy &= \int 1-tan(x+y)dx
\end{align*}

$(1)$ is called Leibniz method (correct me if I'm wrong), and it is quite handy in solving  ODE's.

Answer (score 0):

The equation being $$\frac{dy}{dx}\tan(x+y)=1-\tan(x+y)$$ change, as you did $x+y=u$, that is to say $y=u-x$, $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}-1$. So, the equation rewrite $$(\frac{du}{dx}-1)\tan(u)=1-\tan(u)$$ that is to say $$\frac{du}{dx}=\cot(u)$$ in other words $$\frac{dx}{du}=\tan(u)$$ Integrating both sides $$x+C=-\log (\cos (u))$$ $$\cos(u)=Ce^{-x}$$ $$u=\cos ^{-1}\left(Ce^{-x}\right)$$ $$y=-x+\cos ^{-1}\left(Ce^{-x}\right)$$

Comment: It's better to write $Ce^{-x}$. Also since the inverse cosine is limited to $u \in [0, \pi]$, you're not getting all of the solutions

Comment: @Dylan. You are totally right, indeed ! I edit my answer. Thanks.